# Rvalue reference overloading && operator

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, operator-overloading, conditional-operator

I have been trying examples from the book *Design Patterns in Modern C++: Reusable Approaches for Object-Oriented Software Design by Dmitri Nesteruk* and have been trying to compile an example from S.O.L.I.D. Design principles section.

Here is the code:

```
// This class demonstrates the Open-Closed 
// Principle (OCP) in the S.O.L.I.D. Desgin Principle.
// Software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.)
// should be open for extension, but closed for modification

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum class Color { Red, Green, Blue };
enum class Size { Small, Medium, Large };

struct Product
{
  std::string name;
  Color color;
  Size size;

  explicit Product(std::string name, Color color, Size size) : name{name}, color{color}, size{size} { }  
};

// (Single-Responsibility Principle) our filtering process 
// into two part.
//    1) A filter (a process that takes all items and only returns some)
//    2) A specification (the definition of a predicate to apply to a data element)

// =============== Templates to allow classes to be extended =============== //

template <typename T> struct Specification
{
  virtual bool is_satisfied(T* item) = 0;
};

template <typename T> struct Filter {
  virtual std::vector<T*> filter(std::vector<T*>&, Specification<T>& ) = 0;
};

template< typename T > struct Display {
  virtual void display(const std::vector<T*>&) = 0;
};

// ========== Product Filter ========== //
struct BetterProductFilter : Filter<Product>{
  std::vector<Product*> filter(std::vector<Product*>& items, Specification<Product>& spec) override {
    std::vector<Product*> result;

    for (auto& p : items){
      if (spec.is_satisfied(p)){
        result.push_back(p);
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
};

// ========== Color specification ========== //
struct ColorSpecification : Specification<Product>{

  Color color;

  ColorSpecification(const Color color) : color{color} {}

  bool is_satisfied(Product* item) override { return item->color == color; }
};

// ========== Size specification ========== //

struct SizeSpecification : Specification<Product>{

  Size size;

  SizeSpecification(const Size size) : size{size} {}

  bool is_satisfied(Product* item) override { return item->size == size; }
  
};

// ========== Product Display ========== ///
struct ProductDisplay : Display<Product>{
  void display(const std::vector<Product*> &items){
    for(auto &item : items){
      std::cout << item->name << std::endl;
    }
  }

};

// =============== Allowing Composite Specifications =============== //
template <typename T> struct AndSpecification : Specification<T>
{
  Specification<T> &first;
  Specification<T> &second;

  AndSpecification(Specification<T> &first, Specification<T> &second) 
    : first(first), second(second) {}

  bool is_satisfied(T *item) override {
    return first.is_satisfied(item) && second.is_satisfied(item);
  }
};

// Overloading the && operator for two specifications
template <typename T> AndSpecification<T> operator&&
  (Specification<T>& first, Specification<T>& second){
  return AndSpecification<T>(first, second);
}

// ======= Rvalue Reference Doesn't work with our class implementation ====== //
template <typename T> AndSpecification<T> operator&&
  (Specification<T>&& first, Specification<T>&& second){
  return AndSpecification<T>(first, second);
}

int main(){

  // Initialization of Products
  Product apple{ "Apple", Color::Green, Size::Small };
  Product tree{ "Tree", Color::Green, Size::Large };
  Product house{ "House", Color::Blue, Size::Large };

  // Place all the products into a vector
  std::vector<Product*> all {&apple, &tree, &house};

  // Filter & Specification Objects
  BetterProductFilter filterObj;

  // Avoid making extra variables for specifications
  //ColorSpecification green(Color::Green);
  //SizeSpecification large(Size::Large);
  //auto green_and_large = green && large;

  auto green_and_large = ColorSpecification(Color::Green) && SizeSpecification(Size::Large);

  // Composite Specifications
  //AndSpecification<Product> green_and_large{ large, green };

  // Product Display Object 
  ProductDisplay disp;
  
  auto filtered_items = filterObj.filter(all, green_and_large);

  disp.display(filtered_items);

  return 0;
}
```

I overloaded the && operator to accepts two references to existing objects and that seems to work fine in this snippet of code:

```
// Overloading the && operator for two specifications
template <typename T> AndSpecification<T> operator&&
  (Specification<T>& first, Specification<T>& second){
  return AndSpecification<T>(first, second);
}
```

In main:

```
ColorSpecification green(Color::Green);
SizeSpecification large(Size::Large);
auto green_and_large = green && large;
```

But when I use Rvalue references I end up with a segmentation fault using this code:

```
// ======= Rvalue Reference Doesn't work with our class implementation ====== //
    template <typename T> AndSpecification<T> operator&&
      (Specification<T>&& first, Specification<T>&& second){
      return AndSpecification<T>(first, second);
    }
```

In main:

```
auto green_and_large = ColorSpecification(Color::Green) && SizeSpecification(Size::Large);
```

I'm guessing it is the fact this implementation calls AndSpecification(first, second) and this constructor only handles references to existing objects and not to rvalue references. How could I modify the code above to allow && operator to work with Rvalue references? Thanks!!!

Comment: Since `AndSpecification` stores references, you need to make sure that the objects it references live longer than it does. (The use of reference members makes me wonder whether this book is actually any good.)

Answer (score 0):

Your conclusion is correct.

If you just want to get a program.

```cpp
// it is your ColorSpecification class with copy constructor addition
struct ProductColorSpecification final : Specification<Product> {
    Color color;
    ProductColorSpecification(const Color color)
    : Specification<Product>()
    , color{color}
    {}
    ProductColorSpecification(const ProductColorSpecification& o)
    : Specification<Product>()
    , color{o.color}
    {}
    bool is_satisfied(Product* item) const override { return item->color == color; }
};

// it is your SizeSpecification class with copy constructor addition
struct ProductSizeSpecification final : Specification<Product> {
    Size size;
    ProductSizeSpecification(const Size size)
    : Specification<Product>()
    , size{size} {}
    ProductSizeSpecification(const ProductSizeSpecification& o)
    : Specification<Product>()
    , size{o.size}
    {}
    bool is_satisfied(Product* item) const override { return item->size == size; }
};

struct ProductAndSpecification final : Specification<Product> {
    ProductColorSpecification *color_spec;
    ProductSizeSpecification  *size_spec ;
    ProductAndSpecification(const Specification<Product>& first_spec, const Specification<Product>& second_spec)
    : Specification<Product>()
    , color_spec{nullptr}
    , size_spec{nullptr}
    {
        const auto* spec_f_c = dynamic_cast<const ProductColorSpecification*>(&first_spec );
        const auto* spec_f_s = dynamic_cast<const ProductSizeSpecification *>(&first_spec );
        const auto* spec_s_c = dynamic_cast<const ProductColorSpecification*>(&second_spec);
        const auto* spec_s_s = dynamic_cast<const ProductSizeSpecification *>(&second_spec);
        if (spec_f_c && spec_s_s) {
            color_spec = new ProductColorSpecification(*spec_f_c);
            size_spec  = new ProductSizeSpecification (*spec_s_s);
        } else if (spec_f_s && spec_s_c) {
            color_spec = new ProductColorSpecification(*spec_s_c);
            size_spec  = new ProductSizeSpecification (*spec_f_s);
        } else {
            //  bad specs
        }
    }
    ~ProductAndSpecification()
    {
        if (color_spec)
            delete color_spec;
        if (size_spec)
            delete size_spec;
    }

    friend ProductAndSpecification operator&&(Specification<Product>&& first, Specification<Product>&& second);

    bool is_satisfied(Product *item) const override {
        if (color_spec && size_spec)
            return color_spec->is_satisfied(item) && size_spec->is_satisfied(item);
        else if (color_spec)
            return color_spec->is_satisfied(item);
        else if (size_spec)
            return size_spec->is_satisfied(item);
        else
            return false;
    }
};

struct ProductAndSpecification operator&&(Specification<Product>&& first, Specification<Product>&& second) {
    return ProductAndSpecification(first, second);
}
```

But it still bad design (I guess you see why).

PS:: Don't forget to change specification object in main function.

Comment: I tried that but my Specification<T> struct has no constructor, which I want because it is an abstract class, so  I cannot create an object of that type.

Comment: You are right, answer was edited. There are heap allocation because you need default Color and Size definition inside the ProductAndSpecification class otherwise,